# ld: cannot find /lib64/libpthread.so.0 ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a

Tags: pip, conda, ld

Background:

```
pip install 'openfold @ git+https://github.com/aqlaboratory/openfold.git@4b41059694619831a7db195b7e0988fc4ff3a307'
~anaconda3/envs/esmfold/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib64/libpthread.so.0: 没有那个文件或目录                                                
~/anaconda3/envs/esmfold/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a: 没有那个文件或目录
```

Essential reason:

The default g++ (used when run python setup.py install --user) can't find the `/lib64/libpthread.so.0` and `/usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a`.

Solve superficial reason:

1. Download gxx version through `conda install 'gxx=9.5.0'`
2. Config the gxx for pip install `export CFLAGS='-Wl,sysroot='~/anaconda3/envs/esmfold/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot'`
3. Run pip install again, congratulation, it works！

Comment: What is the question? Without more general scope, this seems better fit for a post on [the OpenFold repository](https://github.com/aqlaboratory/openfold) rather than here.